# Decoding Java Bouncy Castle encoded PGP message with openpgp-js: No public key encrypted session key packet found

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, bouncycastle, openpgp

I am trying to decode a custom PGP message created in other application with Bouncy Castle library for Java. According to the params, it uses SHA512 to hash and RSA to encode and decode. The key's length is 1024 bits.

```
const publicKeyArmored = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.65

...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
`;

const privateKeyArmored = `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.65

...
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
`;
const passphrase = 'password';

const encrypted = `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: BCPG v1.65

...
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
`;

async function run() {

    const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyArmored })
    const privateKey = await openpgp.decryptKey({
        privateKey: await openpgp.readPrivateKey({ armoredKey: privateKeyArmored }),
        passphrase,
        config: { minRSABits: 1024, preferredHashAlgorithm: openpgp.enums.hash.sha512 }
    })

    const message = await openpgp.readMessage({ armoredMessage: encrypted })

    const options = {
        message: message,
        decryptionKeys: privateKey
    }

    const decrypted = await openpgp.decrypt(options);

    console.log(decrypted.data)
}
```

This code is supposed to be able to decode PGP message once encoded by BouncyCastle library with the given public key. We also have the private one and the correct passphrase for it.

If we use this keypair to encode and then decode custom text entirely with openpgp-js, everything works fine, but when we try to decode an existing message with the given keypair (the message was encoded with the same keypair, of course), we get an error on decoding:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error decrypting message: No public key encrypted session key packet found.
    at cc.decryptSessionKeys (C:\dev\other\encryption\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:335642)
    at cc.decrypt (C:\dev\other\encryption\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:2:334457)
    at Object.exports.decrypt (C:\dev\other\encryption\node_modules\openpgp\dist\node\openpgp.min.js:16:132458)
```

The other issues about this error actually tell about old API, and the problems usually were quite simple: like the password was set in decryption params making library think that the message is encoded with the password, not with a keypair.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi, @NiveshKrishna! Unfortunately, no=(

Comment: Apparently there was an issue in our java app, we had to pass pgp key as parameter while encrypting. Hope this helps someone : https://gitlab.e.foundation/dapsi-e2ee/nextcloud-notes/-/commit/a2447c7612ce158dc3341d655f450c1829694436